# Reversible Petrification: What is going on on an atomic level?

Tags: magic, chemistry, biochemistry

So, I'll try to keep this short.

the petrification spell turns people to stone... or gold... or some other material. For the purposes of this discussion, we'll say the caster can choose any solid material which is stable at room temperature. (some such materials may still not be viable, given the restrictions imposed below. This should also work on most other things under a given mass, but people are probably the most complicated thing this could happen to.)

In all cases, the spell is reversible.

It's important to note that to reverse the effect, the spells are able to intuit the "proper" form of a person based on the atomic arrangement of their petrified form, rather than "remembering" what their chemical composition was before the transition.

so...

What is going on on a chemical level? what is happening to the atoms during personification, and how are they arranged afterwards?

does this effect require atoms (or individual protons, neutrons, and electrons) to be pulled in from the environment?

what magical effect is able to turn someone into stone, gold, e.t.c., and then turn them back without remembering what their atomic composition was before the transition?

Also, what properties will the petrified person have as a result of these restrictions? Will a person turned to gold be far lighter and more fragile than a conventional solid gold statue, for example?

Comment: Why are you asking us how your magic works? you create it, you decide how it works.

Comment: I am not a chemistry expert and was simply asking for advice.

Comment: You've kind of killed the best two answers I could think of. Either the petrification process leaves a coding in mineral of the original composition of the person (a sort of data fossilization) or you have an Akashic record of the original person in a higher dimension the spell accesses and then recapitulates.

Comment: @DWKraus Indeed. It appears there's no good way to meet the requirements I've specified. This is, of course, an acceptable answer.

Comment: I was going to suggest trehalose (standard cryptobiosis, like you were sending astronauts to another star).  But the "any material" scratches that.  Then you want to *remove* "any material" without disrupting the organism, even though some of it might have been made out of that material.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want no "configuration memory" involved in following the transformation in both ways, I think your only solution is to add a constant number of nucleons and electrons to each atom in the body to increase its atomic number when petrifying it, and subtract the same number of nucleons and electrons when you want to unpetrify it.

For example, adding 8 protons, 8 neutrons and 8 electrons to an atom of carbon would turn it into an atom of silicon, which happens to be a major component of rocks.

However mind that finding a constant number which doesn't mess things up it's going to be impossible I think: for example with the above 8, you would turn hydrogen into nitrogen, and oxygen into sulfur. A COOH group,  just to give you an example, would turn into a SiSSN, which is nowhere existing in a stable form. An NH group would turn into PF, which again I think it doesn't exists. Thus your "rock" would be a incoherent mass of atoms which do not want to stay together and will want to separate or form different compounds.

Moreover you risk of creating unstable nuclei, which might decay and for which the reverse process would not return the starting atom.

Since you are going with magic, let it be magic: maybe in a part of the stone there is encoded the mapping of each original state of the transmuted stone, and the reverse spell reads it.

Answer (score 3):

### Because Magic, *but*:

The only way your spell can do this, yet in-and-of-itself access no information is if the petrification process replicates the position of the person's atoms perfectly with alternative elements which are then bound exactly in the positions the original atoms were in. Every type of atom correlates with either a specific replacement element, or possibly an isotope of the element. Each new atom is unable to move at all unless the whole construct is magically broken (at which point, the petrification would become irreversible). This means the petrified person doesn't interact with the surrounding world until whatever "breaking" criteria are met that makes the petrification permanent.

Each atom, while unable to move, retains the kinetic energy of the atoms it displaced, storing that energy and unable to release it. So the spell needs no actual information to work- HOWEVER, the static position and conserved energy of the atoms, combined with the dedicated specific materials the petrification creates, means there is a lot of information that "incidentally" is stored in the final state of the petrified person. There would also need to be the energy of various bonds stored between the atoms or else the person would almost fall apart/explode on re-transformation as every bond broke and the stored energy in the bonds was instantaneously released.

The spell itself just goes, "Carbon to gold, lock energy state. Hydrogen to lithium, lock energy state." They become a metal statue. The whole statue would need to behave like a single thing for purposes of kinetics or gravity. You said stone/metal, but if you want to simplify the whole thing, they can retain their original atomic composition, and simply freeze all atoms in the body relative to each other while retaining the energy states of the original person conserved within the spell.

The reverse spell simply converts each atom to it's corresponding atom, and then releases the stored kinetic energy of each individual original atom into the resulting retransformed atom, and finally unbinds the atoms from each other. The spell itself needs to have no information put in. The matter itself retains the information completely by virtue of stored energy and elemental composition.

It may or may not be mobile, it may or may not not interact with light. That's up to you. Magically, this is a transmutation spell, and the atoms are transformed into new atoms. So new atoms are not created from nothing (although mass is not conserved, unless the original elemental state is kept). No matter is brought in from elsewhere (unless it's somehow extradimensional). Because the individual atoms are fixed in position relative to each other, the statue would be incredibly hard (virtually unbreakable without also breaking the spell). The ***most*** conservative interpretation would be that the statue is immovable (possibly even ripping away/through the moving planet) but I'm guessing you'd want it to AT LEAST interact as a cohesive object relative to it's surroundings. If the energy states of the surface atoms are changeable, the statue could be visible and look like the transformed material (In this case, the outermost edge of atoms might be able to chemically react as well, but probably not by the logic of the enchantment). Otherwise light could not be absorbed and would assumedly reflect off the surface (and I'm guessing it would look a bit like a mirror).

If this was able to petrify non-living things (something like wood), it could create virtually indestructible building blocks or magically indestructible boards/materials, but with the weight of whatever elements it was transformed into. Transformed back, it would be wooden blocks. Otherwise I imagine stacking sheep on top of a wall with limbs placed over the previous sheep, then transformed to become the next part of the wall.

"Broken" petrified things would simply retain the properties of the material they had been transformed into. So break the petrification into gold and you get gold you can use. The thermodynamics and energy release of "breaking" a petrified person are really complex and could result in some strange effects, but I'm guessing it would release a lot of heat as all the stored energy of bonds and kinetics of individual atoms came out of the spell (but it's magic, so who knows?).